# Open source push-to-talk encrypted app

Tags: android, open-source, voip

I'm looking for an open source push-to-talk (walkie-talkie) software for Android, preferably with secure end-to-end encryption.

Seems like [Jitsi](https://jitsi.org/) declares that it has the push-to-talk feature, however I still wasn't been able to find how to enable it.

Comment: From Android to Android, right? (So a solution is not *preferred* but *required* to be for Android?)

Comment: Yes, Android is require. But we haven't been able to find _any_ open source solution of this kind.

Comment: Personally, my current guess would be mumble… But I'm still searching as libs don't seems easy to integrate in other custom software.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple, only tangentially related questions that would be better served being posted separately. Answering one of them...

> Any tutorials/docs on how to get Jitsi work in walkie-talkie mode are highly appreciated.

I just attempted to use this featured and determined that is works in the same way as the Skype PTT feature, which is to say it is just a glorified mute button, with inverse logic. It does nothing to address rapid call setup, which is also a necessary part of what has come to be considered a PTT service.

According to the Jitsi [release announcement](https://jitsi.org/Main/News) for version 2.2 (2013.04.30):

> Adds “push to talk” functionality (quick unmute while pressing Ctrl+Shift+T).

So you place a call, click some mute button in the UI, then use the Ctrl+Shift+T shortcut to unmute when you want to talk. (Messages in the Jitsi mailing list archives suggest you can change the key combination used for this.)

Comment: "that would be better served being posted separately" **and elsewhere**. Only the first paragraph of the question is on-topic for this site, and this answer, though helpful, addresses the off-topic parts.